# Access YAML file in Cucumber

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have some cucumber tests that I'm writing, and to test different scenarios I setup a config.yml file. I load it in in my env.rb using:

```
require 'calabash-cucumber/cucumber'
require 'yaml'

# Config file to hold user settings
#CONFIG = YAML::load_file(File.join(File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__)), 'config.yml'))
CONFIG = YAML.load_file("features/support/config.yml")
```

The commented out line is another variation I've tried to load the file.

When I call the data, I do so like this:

```
@userName = CONFIG[env.to_sym][side.to_sym][type.to_sym][:username]
```

Yet, when it gets to this line, it gives me the following error:

```
"undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)"
```

(The `[]` is an empty square box in the console.)

I'm not sure how to rectify this issue, I'm 99% sure I'm loading the YAML file correctly and using it correctly.

Any ideas or suggestions would be great!

Edit: Sample YAML data:

```
:env:
    :side:
        type:
            :username: "username"
```

Comment: The problem for us trying to help you is that the error message doesn't tell *which* index is failing because you've chained a number of them together. Don't do that, especially for debugging. Break the chain into separate lines so you can get a more usable message, one that specifies a particular line number. When asking for help debugging we need input data and an example of your expected output.

Comment: Would you please provide yml file example with dummy data? And that is `env`, 'side', 'type'?

Comment: Try to use strings instead of symbols:  `@userName = CONFIG['env']['side']['type']['username']`

Comment: Using Strings instead of symbols won't necessarily fix a thing since we don't know what's in his YAML. YAML in Ruby supports symbols.

Comment: @theTinMan, I'd guess that's exactly his issue, because hash is not symbolized by default when you load from `.yml` file.

Comment: Again, if his YAML contains `:foo:`, the resulting key will `:foo` after being parsed by YAML. Until we know what is in the YAML we're just shooting in the dark. That's why it's essential to provide sample input.

Comment: @theTinMan, oh, I see. I didn't know that symbols will be parsed. Thanks!

Comment: I just added some sample input. Don't know much about this, kind of just got thrown in the deep end so I'm learning as I go. Let me know if you guys need anything else!

Answer (score 0):

Say you have `config.yml` file:

```
env:
  side:
    type:
      username: 'User'
```

`YAML.load_file()` won't symbolize hash by default, so you need to access values using string, not symbols.

```
puts @userName = CONFIG['env']['side']['type']['username']
#=> User
```

**Update:**

As mentioned by [the Tin Man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128421/the-tin-man), it depends what is your YML file look like.

Loading this `yml` file would produce symbolized hash:

```
:env:
  :side:
    :type:
      :username: 'User'
```

So if you want to access username key:

```
@userName = CONFIG[:env][:side][:type][:username]
```

Comment: Change the keys to `:env:`, `:side:`, `:type:` and `:username:` and see what happens.

Comment: I was using YAML::load_file() originally, however being so new to Ruby (just got put on this project at my company) I don't know the difference so I just switched versions. It sounds like I wanted the original version.

Comment: @theTinMan, thank you. I didn't know that you can put symbols in yml file and it will be parsed as symbolized hash.